# How do i count each text character output on str_split text line

Tags: string, split, count, character, each

I have this code which output '1234' '5678' '910' for text line of '12345678910' my problem is do i count  each character output so i do on it

i like my output result this way example '1234' '5678' 'uncompleted' instead of '1234' 5678' '910' i have tried this code:

```
$txt = "12345678910";

 $disp = str_split($txt, 4); 

 for ($b = 0; $b<3; $b++) {
     $play = "$b"; 
    foreach($play as $count); 

  if($count != 4)  
  { 
echo " uncompleted";
 }
```

echo "$disp[$b]";
     }

i get no result with this code  thanks for your time and understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, there are many errors.

I guess you want:

```
$txt = "12345678910";
# split string in pieces with 4 characters
$disp = str_split($txt, 4);
# loop on all pieces
foreach($disp as $piece) {
    # length is not 4
    if(strlen($piece) != 4) { 
        echo "uncompleted";
    } else {
        echo "$piece ";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1234 5678 uncompleted
```

Comment: thanks for your impact in my solution but i want to be able to output in this function


     for($b = 0; $b<3; $b++);


    $txt = "12345678910";

    # split string in pieces with 4 characters

    $disp = str_split($txt, 4);

    for($b = 0; $b<3; $b++){

    # loop on all pieces

    foreach($disp[$b] as $piece) {

        # length is not 4

        if(strlen($piece) != 4) { 

            echo "uncompleted";

        } else {

            echo "$piece[$b] ";

        }

    }
    }

Comment: @EniediMonday: Sorry, I don't get you. Doesn't this work as you want?

Comment: It work but not perfect as wanted want to alter each result according to  `$b`  quantity example 
   `for($b = 0; $b<3; $b++)`
  1 $pieces[$b] 1234
  2 $pieces[$b] 5678
  3 $pieces[$b] uncompleted 
  thanks for your understanding returns